# Find-replace code through vba gets ignored

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word, find

I cannot seem to get the VBA code that finds and replaces words in the word document to work. 
I can find the words in the word document manually, but the vba code has no effect.

Hello,

I am trying to create a custom form in word through an excel input sheet. My issue is that the code that finds and replaces the words in the word document gets ignored in vba even while the word document is open (I can manually find the words in the document). Opening the word file through VBA is not an issue.

Could someone please show me how to find and replace words in my word document?

As displayed in the code below, I alreay tried the "With.WordDoc.Content.find" method without success.

Below I added the code to find one of the words

Thank you!

```
Sub CreateWordDocuments()

Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, TemplName, FileName As String
Dim WordDoc, Wordapp As Object
Dim RownumDocLoc As Integer

Dim inputsheet As Worksheet
Set inputsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")

Dim templatesheet As Worksheet
Set templatesheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates")


inputsheet.Activate
templaterow = Application.Match("Template:", Columns("B:B"), 0)


If inputsheet.Cells(templaterow, 4) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please complete the template criteria", , "No template selected"
        inputsheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
        Exit Sub
End If


TemplName = inputsheet.Cells(templaterow, 4)


templatesheet.Activate
RownumDocLoc = Application.Match(TemplName, Columns("F:F"), 0)
DocLoc = templatesheet.Cells(RownumDocLoc, 7) & "\" & TemplName



'Open Word Template
On Error Resume Next 
Set Wordapp = GetObject("Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then 

Err.Clear
Set Wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Wordapp.Visible = True 

End If

'Open Template
Set WordDoc = Wordapp.documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False)

With WordDoc.Content.Find
    .Text = "samplestring"
    .Replacement.Text = "adjustedstring"
    .wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceall
End With


End Sub
```

I would expect the string "samplestring" to be adjusted to "adjustedstring" in the word file. However nothing happens when the code runs (no errors).

Comment: Do you have a reference in the VBA solution for Microsoft Word?

Comment: Comment out this line `On Error Resume Next ` (which you should *never* use for an entire procedure!) then try again. Let us know where and what error(s) are generated. If you have it for starting up the Word instance, put `On Error GoTo 0` immediately after `Err.Clear`.

Comment: I commented out the on error resume next and found out that the WordDoc variable was not defined properly. The text is being replaced in the word document now. Thank you for the advice!